# Каким средством почистить монитор?

Tags: железо

Да, вот еще вопрос на миллион. Печка коптила, чадила, монитор в подтеках - не подтеках, короче, как засаленный, что ли. Пробовали водой - никого, а экспериментировать как-то страшно.

Comment: Какой монитор-то у вас? Модель назовите.

Comment: Ну, вот на нем написано Benq.

Comment: @mathem обратитесь на форум Benq, там более подкованные специалисты.

Comment: А чего это печка чадит? Заслонку поддува проверили, сажей не забило?

Comment: Вы что, смеетесь? Неужели, живя в частном доме, мы бы этого не знали? В этом году мы ее полностью переложили, благо, печник попался дотошный: мы ее  развалили до уровня пола, а он, когда пришел, стал копать еще глубже, представляете? Ну, и не зря копал: там обнаружилось столько косяков... Так что теперь наслаждаемся чистым воздухом в доме.